# Xbox 360 wireless receiver causing issues with my Bluetooth adapter

Tags: windows, bluetooth, xbox360

This is a strange problem, but I'm hoping someone can help. I recently updated to Windows 10, from Windows 7. Everything works well, except I'm running into a very strange issue with the wireless Xbox 360 controller, the receiver, and my Bluetooth adapter.

First, my setup worked flawlessly on Windows 7, the only change has been windows 10.

Here's the issue. After installing the necessary drivers for the 360 wireless receiver (from the CD & updating through device manager) and plugging it in causes my Bluetooth adapter to become unresponsive. I get an error message saying a device is no longer recognized (listed as unknown USB device) and then Bluetooth status bar icon &  driver in device manager dissappear. As you might guess, I lose connection to all my Bluetooth devices immediately as well.

Whats more weird, is that even though the drivers for the Xbox 360 wireless receiver is now listed in device manager, I am unable to connect a wireless 360 controller. The indicator light on the controller continues to blink (each of the 4 quadrant lights are lit).

By disabling the wireless 360 receiver driver and rebooting, Bluetooth works normally.

Comment: This reliever is it a genuine Microsoft receiver or is it a generic device?  Microsoft stop selling the wireless relievers a number of years ago.  Most of the generic devices had lots of compatibility problems even with Windows 7.

Comment: I have a genuine microsoft 360 receiver and a genuine microsoft wireless 360 controller.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 includes drivers for the Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver. You should be able to just plug it in. https://support.xbox.com/en-CA/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-360-wireless-gaming-receiver-windows

If you've installed drivers intended for an older version of Windows, you'll need to uninstall them and clean up whatever damage was caused.

Comment: And FYI, installing drivers from "a CD" is almost always a mistake; they're usually out of date, and sometimes not even compatible with your OS.

Comment: The issue is the same whether I use the CD, or auto loaded driver in Windows 10

Comment: @rakslice - Technically....Windows 10 includes the drivers for the Xbox 360 controller not the Wireless Receiver.

Comment: the windows 10 plug&play driver listed in device manager is listed as "Xbox 360 wireless receiver" not as the controller driver. (I've plugged in a wired 360 controller and seen the separate driver).